# Easiest way to create a timer in seconds?

Tags: c, timer

What is the easiest and simplest way to create a decrementing timer in seconds?

Im using an 8bit microcontroller and cannot use float points or intensive processes. I need a very efficient timer.

Comment: Try using google first: http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_19.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`time(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) is a standard C function for obtaining the current time in seconds since the epoch (midnight on January 1, 1970 UTC).  To make a decrementing timer, you could do something like this:

```
time_t startTime = time(NULL);

time_t timerDuration = 10;  // 10 second timer
time_t endTime = startTime + timerDuration;
while(1)
{
    time_t currTime = time(NULL);
    time_t timeLeft = endTime - currTime;

    if(timeLeft < 0)
    {
        // timer has finished
        break;
    }

    // do stuff - preferably don't spin at 100% CPU
}
```

If you need more precision than 1-second increments, you can use a platform-specific function such as [`gettimeofday(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettimeofday) (POSIX) or [`GetLocalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows).

Comment: Thanks for replying ! When do I initialize the countdown ?? for example I only want the countdown to start after a particular condition.

Comment: Doesnt this countdown start as soon as the program executes ? I want to keep the timer at its given value unless a condition becomes true, thats when the timer starts counting down.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want an *asynchronous* timer. On a 8-bit controller I suppose you don't have multithreading. But you probably have direct access to hardware timers; most 8-bit controllers have several. Either allocate one of the timers for your needs, or use an existing one with known period. It is as efficient as you can get.

Every time the timer ticks, you receive an interrupt. This may be every second or more frequently. Update a variable that keeps time, and return from the interrupt handler (or pass control to a chained handler if you hook on a timer used for other needs).

If the time-keeping variable is over the threshold, that's your event; take your action. Be sure not to make this action take too long, and consult your controller reference regarding actions not allowed within interrupt handlers.